# "HTTP Status code: 404" with Chrome, FireFox and Opera

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm totally new in this, and not sure if it the right place to post it here. 
I used to open my work e-mail (owa) from home with the above mentioned browsers, but recently I'm receiving this error msg when I want to save a draft or trying to send a HTML mail: "Your network connection isn't available. If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk with this HTTP Status code: 404.". I've nothing changed in my PC setting or browsers setting. Fortunately, this error is not happening with IE8. 
Do you know the reason and the fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the internet/network proxy and/or connection. It has nothing to do with HTML. Try re-configuring your internet proxies.

Comment: Thankx for quick response. I'd like to add this point: I have another person who can access his owa on same browser without any issue. What is the recommended config or how I can use the same config for IE8?